# Instr Access VBA - search for Numeric followed by Letter

Tags: ms-access, vba

Sorry if this has been posted elsewhere as I could not find the answer.

I'm trying to search for any number followed by the letter "m" using the `InStr` function. I've got the following code which I thought should have worked however it does not recognise "1m" 1.1m" or any variation and returns 0.

```
Public Function instrstring(strTest As String) As Long

    Dim i As Long

    PosOfFirstDigit = 0
    For i = 1 To Len(strTest)
    If Mid$(strTest, i, 1) Like "#" & "m" Then
    PosOfFirstDigit = i
    Exit For
    End If
    Next

End Function
```

I appreciate your help!

Comment: Your `Mid$` is extracting a single character, and then your `If` is comparing that single character to see if it is `Like` "#m".  It won't be - one character won't be like a number followed by the letter "m".  Try using `Mid$(strTest, i, 2)` if you want to compare two characters.  (But change your `For` to `For i = 1 To Len(strTest) - 1`.)

Comment: `#` represents "digit" and not "number". Plus what @YowE3K said.  Seems like you might need a regular expression for this, but it's difficult to tell without some samples of the text you're dealing with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To return the position of the match something like this:

For

> "a1.1m"
>   "testme 1m"
>   "testme 222"

Returns

> 2
>   8
>   not found

```
Sub Impeached()

Debug.Print StrOut("a1.1m")
Debug.Print StrOut("testme 1m")
Debug.Print StrOut("testme 222")

End Sub
```

*code*

```
Public Function StrOut(strIn As String) As String
Dim objRegex As Object
Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With objRegex
     .Pattern = "(\d*\.)?\dm"
     If .Test(strIn) Then
        StrOut = InStr(strIn, .Execute(strIn)(0))
     Else
        StrOut = "not found"
     End If
End With

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Tim Williams has mentioned, it's best using regular expressions (Regex) for this if you're having floats as well as integers.

You'll need to setup the reference to Regex to use it. Add VBA reference to **"Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5"**

The regex you'll need is

```
Dim RE As New RegExp
With RE
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "\d*?\.\dm"
End With

If RE.Test(strTest) Then
    Msgbox("Found!")
    'Insert the function you want to perform here
End If
```